# Why value stored in an interface is not addressable in Golang

Tags: go

Citing the golang wiki (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MethodSets#interfaces):

"The concrete value stored in an interface is not addressable, in the same way, that a map element is not addressable."

The question of map values not being addressable is explained here:
[Why are map values not addressable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168329/why-are-map-values-not-addressable)

However, it is not clear regarding the interface. Why are they not addressable? Is this because of some hard design assumption?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Types of Go struct methods that satisfy an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015114/types-of-go-struct-methods-that-satisfy-an-interface/41016448#41016448).

Comment: What good would a copy being addressable do, besides add more cognitive overhead to the language? Addressability is already taken care of by pointer values.

Comment: Well, it would allow satisfying interface by pointer receivers...

Comment: @Lemurata Yes, and if the pointer method would require to modify the receiver, any modification it would do would be lost, and you would scratch your head twice as hard why it doesn't work.

Comment: @icza I would like to allow pointer receiver to modify the original structure not a copy. I don't understand why its impossible.

Comment: @Lemurata Because the value in the interface wrapper is already a copy, a detached version from the original, it doesn't store the address of the original. So a pointer receiver could only get the address of the copy and not that of the original.

Comment: @icza sounds good... so the true question is: why (by design) is the value in the interface wrapper a copy, not for example pointer to the original value?

Comment: @Lemurata Because everything in Go is passed by value. This is for consistency.

Comment: @Lemurata You can also read something about this in this answer: [How can a slice contain itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077566/how-can-a-slice-contain-itself/36078970#36078970)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Why isn't a non-pointer value stored in an interface addressable? This is an excellent question, and the answer explains why an interface containing a non-pointer value can't be the receiver for a method with a pointer receiver, leading to the dreaded error:

```
<type> does not implement <interface> (<name> method has pointer receiver)
```

**tl;dr**

A non-pointer value stored in an interface isn't addressable to maintain type integrity. For example, a pointer to ***A***, which points to a value of type ***A*** in an interface, would be invalidated when a value of a different type ***B*** is subsequently stored in the interface.

Because a non-pointer value stored in an interface isn't addressable, the compiler can't pass its address to a method with a pointer receiver.

**Long answer**

The answers I've seen online don't make much sense.  For instance, [this article](https://npf.io/2014/05/intro-to-go-interfaces/) says:

> The reason is that the value in an interface is in a hidden memory
>   location, and so the compiler can’t automatically get a pointer to
>   that memory for you (in Go parlance, this is known as being “not
>   addressable”).

It's true that the value stored in an interface is not addressable, but as far as I can see it's not because its stored in "a hidden memory location".

Another common answer is:

> When an interface value is created, the value that is wrapped in the interface is copied. It is therefore not possible to take its address, and even if you did, using a pointer to the interface value would have unexpected effects (ie. unable to alter the original copied value).

This makes no sense, since a pointer to a value copied into an interface would be no different than a pointer to a value copied into a concrete type; in both cases you can't alter the original copied value through the pointer to the copy.

So why isn't a value stored in an interface addressable?  The answer lies in the follow-on implications if it *were* addressable.

Let's say you have an interface, ***I***, and two types, ***A*** and ***B***, which satisfy that interface:

```
type I interface{}
type A int
type B string
```

Create an ***A*** and store it in an ***I***:

```
func main() {
    var a A = 5
    var i I = a
    fmt.Printf("i is of type %T\n", i)
```

Let's pretend we could take the address of a value stored in an interface:

```
    var aPtr *A
    aPtr = &(i.(A)) // not allowed, but if it were...
```

Now create a ***B*** and store it in ***i***:

```
    var b B = "hello"
    i = b
    fmt.Printf("i is of type %T, aPtr is of type %T\n", i, aPtr)
}
```

Here's the output:

```
i is of type main.A
i is of type main.B, aPtr is of type *main.A
```

After putting a ***B*** into ***i***, what is ***aPtr*** pointing to?  ***aPtr*** was declared as pointing to an ***A***, but ***t*** now contains a ***B***, and ***aPtr*** is no longer a valid pointer to ***A***.

This, however is permitted:

```
    var aPtr *A
    var a2 A = i.(A)
    aPtr = &a2
```

Because the second line makes a copy of the value in ***i.(A)***, and ***aPtr*** does not point to ***i.(A)***.

So, why can't an interface containing a non-pointer value be the receiver for a method with a pointer receiver? Because a non-pointer value stored in an interface isn't addressable, so the compiler can't pass its address to a method with a pointer receiver.

Comment: Here's some code in the playground illustrating this: https://play.golang.org/p/eeaYzqZsmOs

Comment: Thanks for explaining instead of stating "you should ask another question", like the others do.

Comment: You don't have to make your reasoning for non-addressability of interface values. Go doesn't let it because it's an implementation detail and that's why Go spec disallows it. So different Go compilers (and versions) are free to choose whatever semantics they want for interface values. Interfaces were not always two-word structures.

Comment: "it's an implementation detail" with serious consequences as noted in my post

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is "because Go does not have references". If you call `Foo(x)` you know `x` won't be modified; if you call `Foo(&x)`, you expect that it might. If what you request would be possible (in particular, if you want the *value itself* to be addressed, not the copy made in the interface), then that would break down:

```
func Bar() {
    b := 42
    Foo(b)
    fmt.Println(b)
}

func Foo(v interface{}) {
    // Making up syntax now
    p = takeAddressAs(v).(*int)
    *p = 23
}
```

Note, that it *is* possible (from a technical perspective) to [address](https://play.golang.org/p/FrMtB0szvoD) the copy stored in an interface and it definitely would be possible to build a language in which it would be allowed to modify the original value too (like you seem to want): This is basically how Python works. You could just make `v = x` be syntactic sugar for `v = &x` when `v` is of interface type. But that would add reference values to Go, which it *intentionally* lacks.

I think the root cause of the confusion here is that Go has syntactic sugar to call `b.Foo()`, even if `Foo` has a pointer receiver (as long as `b` is addressable). It's reasonable to be confused that you can call `b.Write()` but you can't do `fmt.Fprintln(b, 42)`. Arguably, Go should just not have that sugar and instead require you to explicitly do `(&b).Write` or just make it a pointer to begin with (using, e.g. `b := new(bytes.Buffer)` instead of `var b bytes.Buffer`). But the answer to that is a) it's terribly convenient and b) it didn't seem *that* unexpected, that `b.Foo()` might modify `b`.

**tl;dr** is: a) Go does not have references, b) there is no technical reason it couldn't have them (contrary to the other answers' claims) but c) Go decided not to want them.

Comment: This question ("Why value stored in an interface is not addressable in Golang") is interesting because of an inconsistency in how Go handles pointer method receivers.  If such a method is called with a non-pointer concrete value, Go will pass the receiver a pointer to the value, but not in the case where the value is stored in an interface.  There can be no pointer to a reified value in an interface, because that could compromise type safety.

Answer (score 0):

An interface in Go is the definition of methods that a type must provide if it is to be used as a type of the interface.

The code that uses an interface isn't concerned with how the implementing type does this under the covers, it just cares that the interface methods are satisfied.

As an example, lets suppose I have a simple logger interface that my code uses:

```
type Logger interface {
    Printf(format string, args ...interface{})
    Errorf(format string, args ...interface{})
}
```

I can use this interface all through my code. I'll need to supply an implementation of `Logger` where it's required. There may be several implementations. I may have a `FileLogger` that writes to a file. Should my code be able to access, for example, the `File` property in the `FileLogger`?

I may have a `ConsoleLogger` and a `SockerLogger` and a `LogglyLogger` all of which satisfy the interface. But it makes no sense in any of these to even have a `File` property. If my code that uses `Logger` interface was interested in the underlying `File`, what would it do when using these other `Logger` implementations?

If you need to access the underlying data in an interface implementation, you are probably using interfaces incorrectly.

A way around this is perhaps using Getter/Setters on the interface? If you really need access to a value from the underlying structure, make that part of the interface. In the example above a `GetFile()` won't make much sense but perhaps there are other situations where all implementations of an interface share a common attribute e.g. `GetLen()` and `SetLen()`?

Answer (score 0):

Helpful info in go doc:https://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets

> Even in cases where the compiler could take the address of a value to
> pass to the method, if the method modifies the value the changes will
> be lost in the caller. As an example, if the Write method of
> bytes.Buffer used a value receiver rather than a pointer, this code:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
io.Copy(buf, os.Stdin)
```

would copy standard input into a copy of buf, not into buf itself. This is almost never the desired behavior.