# Pointers & Interfaces in Go

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong here.. all responses appreciated  :)

If uncomment "// grow()" works,

else errors:

> prog.go:38:2: impossible type switch case: p (type plant) cannot have
>   dynamic type plant1 (grow method has pointer receiver) prog.go:39:16:
>   impossible type assertion:    plant1 does not implement plant (grow
>   method has pointer receiver) prog.go:40:2: impossible type switch
>   case: p (type plant) cannot have dynamic type plant2 (grow method has
>   pointer receiver) prog.go:41:16: impossible type assertion:   plant2
>   does not implement plant (grow method has pointer receiver)
>   prog.go:60:12: cannot use p1 (type plant1) as type plant in argument
>   to showHeight:    plant1 does not implement plant (grow method has
>   pointer receiver) prog.go:61:12: cannot use p2 (type plant2) as type
>   plant in argument to showHeight:  plant2 does not implement plant
>   (grow method has pointer receiver)

https://play.golang.org/p/oMv7LdW85yK

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type plant1 struct {
    name   string
    height int
}

type plant2 struct {
    species string
    height  int
}

func (self *plant1) grow() {
    self.height++
}
func (self *plant2) grow() {
    self.height++
}

func (self plant1) getHeight() int {
    return self.height
}
func (self plant2) getHeight() int {
    return self.height
}

type plant interface {
    getHeight() int
    //grow()
}

func showHeight(p plant) {
    switch p.(type) {
    case plant1:
        fmt.Println(p.(plant1).name, `Height = `, p.(plant1).getHeight())
    case plant2:
        fmt.Println(p.(plant2).species, `Height = `, p.(plant2).getHeight())
    }

}

func main() {

    p1 := plant1{
        name:   `Plant 10`,
        height: 1,
    }
    p2 := plant2{
        species:   `Plant 20`,
        height: 1,
    }
    p1.grow()
    p1.grow()
    p2.grow()   

    showHeight(p1)
    showHeight(p2)
}
```

Comment: You defined the grow method on a pointer type, ie `*plant1` not `plant1`. When `p` is the plant interface and you do a type switch on it the switch cases can contain only types that satisfy that interface, ie `*plant1` not `plant1`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/r8Bo92OhMCd

Comment: Note that, when doing a type switch, if you store the type asserted value in a variable then inside the block scope of each case the variable will have the type of that case. And therefore you do not have to do type assertion again inside the cases. ie https://play.golang.org/p/gkSRe9n264w

Comment: Aside: you should generally not mix pointer and non-pointer receivers in methods for a particular type. Choose one and use that for all methods to avoid confusion. https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers. Here, `getHeight` should have a pointer receiver.

Comment: Also note that it's considered bad practice in Go to name method receivers with generic names like "self" or "this". Read any Go code in the standard library, the community, or the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) for examples on idiomatic Go code.

Answer (score 2):

The value you wrap into interface isn't addressable. The value have to be addressable to call methods on pointer receivers. The `grow` methods are declared with pointer receiver. So the compiler sees that `plant` interface is being implemented neither by `plant1` type nor by `plant2` type. Thus you can't pass `plant1` or `plant2` as `plant` to `showHeight` func. And the switch is impossible because implementations of `plant` interface don't include `plant1` and `plant2` types.

See [Why value stored in an interface is not addressable in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790663/why-value-stored-in-an-interface-is-not-addressable-in-golang/48874650#48874650)

Answer (score 0):

Your Function `func showHeight(p plant)` accepts an interface as parameter, and an interface only accepts the types you implement.

Case commented `//grow()`

Since you have commented `grow()` `plant` has only one method `getHeight()` which you have implemented for `plant 1` and `plant 2` and it all goes smooth.

Case uncommented `grow()`

Now none of your types(plant1 or plant 2) implement `plant` interface because `grow()` has been defined on `*plant1` and `*plant2` not on `plant1` and `plant2`. Result; Your function `showHeight(p plant)` which accepts interface type plant, cant accept `pl`,`p2` because these are not of type `plant` anymore.

Fix :

Pass pointers to function as `showHeight(&p1)` and `showHeight(&p2)` and in function definition's cases and print statements, replace `plant1` and `plant2` with `*plant1` and `*plant2`

Confusion which can follow is , `getHeight` has not been implemented on `*plant1` and `*plant2`, why do `*plant1` and `*plant2` are of type `plant`?
Logic: When you pass pointers, values can be derived from these so as to call `getHeight`, but when you pass values, no address can be derived to call `grow()`

SIDENOTE: `p.(*plant2).getHeight()` can be changed to `p.getHeight()` as p is interface and it can call its own methods.

Answer (score 0):

This due to the way the Method Set in Go works. In Go, a Method on a concrete receiver type implements both the value type and pointer type, while a method on a pointer receiver type implements only the pointer value.

In the case of the `grow` method, the pointer receiver type `*plant1/*plant2` are used, so only a pointer value of those types can implement the `grow` method on an interface and the concrete value type can't.

Since the receiver type on `getHeight` method is a concrete receiver type, it implements both the pointer type value (`*plant1/*plant2`) and the type value of both `plant` & `plant2`.

If you change the parameter(p) passed to `showHeight` to a `*plant1/*plant2` type and change the type assertion to expect `*plant1/*plant2` this would solve the error.

check this code example [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/r8Bo92OhMCd)